# Rule to group two facts in prolog?

Tags: prolog, rules

I am writing code for the London tube. I have declared facts that display the name of a station and also which line it is on. e.g.

```
station(aldgate,metropolitan).
station(brixton,victoria).
station(baker,metropolitan).
```

I'm trying to work out a rule that will check whether two stations are on the same line, and which line that is. For example, `aldgate` and `baker` are on the same line, `metropolitan`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? If you don't know where to start, you should try a Prolog tutorial (*e.g.*, [Learn Prolog Now](learnprolognow.org)).

Comment: Thanks man, have had a look at the site and it's very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to work out a rule that will check whether two stations are on the same line, and which line that is.

An example can be the following rule

```
sameLine(Stat1, Stat2, Line) :-
  station(Stat1, Line),
  station(Stat2, Line),
  Stat1 \= Stat2.
```

that is flexible.

It can check of a couple of station is in the same line (calling `sameLine(aldgate, baker, metropolitan)` return true, calling `sameLine(aldgate, baker, Line)` return true and unify `Line` with `metropolitan`) but can find couples of stations of a line (calling `sameLine(Stat1, Stat2, metropolitan)` return true two times, unifying `Stat1` with `aldgate` and `Stat2` with `baker` (the first time) and vice versa (the second time)).

Observe the constraint

```
Stat1 \= Stat2.
```

It's to impose that the two stations are different.

If you want that `sameLine(aldgate, aldgate, Line)` return true unifying `Line` with `metropolitan`, you can delete it.

If you, otherwise, want to avoid the double results (`aldgate`/`baker` and `baker`/`aldgate`, by example, calling `sameLine(Stat1, Stat2, metropolitan)`) you can impose that `Stat1` is non only different than `Stat2` but also that is "before" `Stat2`, replacing

```
Stat1 \= Stat2
```

with

```
Stat1 @< Stat2
```

But, in this way, you obtain true from `sameLine(aldgate, baker, Line)`, but false (because `baker` isn't "before" `aldgate`) from `sameLine(baker, aldgate, Line)`.