# Prolog rule to show list of cities in a country?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to write a rule that will show the cities of a country when given the country itself. Example facts I have written are:

```
city(london,uk).
city(bristol,uk).
city(birmingham,uk).
```

So, I'm trying to work out a rule that will print out "london, bristol, birmingham" when the city "uk" is entered.
Any tips will be useful, Thanks!

Comment: city(City,uk). (dummy to fill minimum of 15 characters for comment).

Comment: Earlier OP question: [Rule to group two facts in prolog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516888/rule-to-group-two-facts-in-prolog)

Comment: Are you self-learning or in a course? If you are in a course then I will only give hints. If you are self-learning, then I would suggest you read a book such as ["Prolog programming for artificial intelligence"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/753559544) by Ivan Bratko or use an online tutorial such as [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/). Also if you state that you are self-learning then I give you more details in an answer.

Comment: Hi, I am self learning. Thanks for the links, I am currently looking through Learn Prolog Now and trying to crack it!

Comment: Since @Boris gave you the answer, I will keep your response in mind on future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list you can try:

```
?- bagof(C, city(C, uk), Cities).
```

PS: I would close your question as "duplicate" if I could find a good and general enough question and answer. This is very basic stuff so maybe that's why I couldn't find it on Stackoverflow.